# gsub non ASCII character in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to replace a non ASCII character from a string with the following code:

```
string.gsub(194.chr,'')
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

RegexpError: premature end of regular expression: /�/

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>> string="foo\xC2bar"
=> "foo\xC2bar"
>> string.force_encoding"ASCII-8BIT"
=> "foo\xC2bar"
>> string.gsub(194.chr, '')
=> "foobar"
```

Comment: so what's the principle here, that this is necessary?

Comment: @roger, The original string object is utf-8 encoded. It doesn't make sense to mix ascii and unicode like this. I think gsub is trying to encode 194.chr to utf-8 before applying the regex, and this is failing because it is not a complete utf-8 character